# Facebook API (Delegate Not Working)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to request data from Facebook using their SDK and I keep getting nothing...

My .h file...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Facebook.h"

@interface VPSettingsViewController : UIViewController <FBRequestDelegate, FBDialogDelegate, FBSessionDelegate> {
    Facebook *facebook;

    NSArray *items;
}

@end
```

Below is my .m file that basically calls a request and is supposed to do something when I receive the request back from Facebook, but *(void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result* never gets called...

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"333593533397126" andDelegate:self];

    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
    NSLog(@"Inside didLoad");
    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        result = [result objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    // When we ask for user infor this will happen.
    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
        //NSDictionary *hash = result;
        NSLog(@"Birthday: %@", [result objectForKey:@"birthday"]);
        NSLog(@"Name: %@", [result objectForKey:@"name"]); 
    }
    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSData class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"Profile Picture");
        //[profilePicture release];
        //profilePicture = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: result];
    }
    NSLog(@"request returns %@",result);
    //if ([result objectForKey:@"owner"]) {}

};
```

It's not that I get any errors, just I never get inside the did load... Nothing is NSLOGing

Also I'm logged in to Facebook on my iPhone...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your request wan't successfull .
Try Implementing the following delegates to know the reason behind the failure:

```
 - (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response;
 - (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
```

Also make sure that your class conforms to protocol `FBRequestDelegate`.